# How can I resize a mongodb capped collection without losing data?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can I resize a mongodb capped collection without losing data?

Is there a command for that, or could somebody provide a script?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You basically need to create a new capped collection and copy the docs to it. This can be done very easily in the javascript (shell), or your language of choice.

```
db.createCollection("new", {capped:true, size:1073741824}); /* size in bytes */
db.old.find().forEach(function (d) {db.new.insert(d)});
db.old.renameCollection("bak", true);
db.new.renameCollection("old", true);
```

**Note**: Just make sure nobody is inserting/updating the old collection when you switch. If you run that code in a db.eval("....") it will lock the server while it runs.

There is a feature request for increasing the size of an existing collection: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1864

Comment: From my point of view, the @Quixrick (posted in 2014, four years after this one) is more "sharp", so it should be marked as "right answer".

Answer (score 54):

This is what I do to resize capped collections:

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "log", size: 1000000000});
```

I already have a Capped Collection named "log".  So I just run the "convertToCapped" on it again, specifying a new size.  I've not tried it on reducing the size of the collection.  That may be something that you'd need to use Scott Hernandez's version on.  But this works for increasing the size of your capped collections without losing any data <s>or your indexes</s>.

---

**EDIT:** @JMichal is correct.  Data is preserved, but indexes are not and will need to be recreated.

Comment: Works for reducing the size of the collection! This should be the right answer.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/ says: 

Warning

This command obtains a global write lock and will block other operations until it has completed.

Comment: But it doesn't preserve indexes, all have to be recreated

Comment: Looks like `convertToCapped` and `cloneCollectionAsCapped` only supports byte size option of the original capped collection creation method. When you need to change the max document count, above answer's method is the only way apparently.

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way to resize the oplog since you can't copy it anywhere

Comment: I'm a bit confused about this answer because MongoDB documentation about `convertToCapped` command at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/ tells that the command *"converts an existing, **non-capped** collection to a capped collection within the same database"*. Thus, under my understanding it cannot be applied to already capped collections. Is my understanding correct? Or maybe documentation at MongoDB site is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/#change-a-capped-collection-s-size

New in version 6.0:

```
db.runCommand( { collMod: "log", cappedSize: 100000 } )
```