# mongoose-js changing capping after collection has been created

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a MEAN js app.

I need to provide a functionality in which the user/admin can decide how many records can be stored in the mongodb collection.

I tried settings the capping to the schema model `{capped:{size:100000,max:12}}`, but it only works while creating schema for first time. I need it to be changeable from 12 to 10 for 20, without dropping the whole collection.

How do i can it after it has been created?

Comment: From what I'm reading, it seems that you cannot change `max` on an existing capped collection.

Comment: @robertklep what about `size`?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22814104/893780), although I've never done that myself.